# Why tomcat is running when I deploy my projects on netbeans using glassfish?

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans, glassfish

I use xampp to open mysql and stop other services. But when I run my servlet project in netbeans it opens glassfish server, at that time in xampp, tomcat status is running. What is the reason?

Comment: Is it causing any problem ?

Comment: @Raúl  No, I just wondered if any people do not have tomcat, can run it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to xampp setings and stop the tomcat server or change its default port from 8080 to anything else. once you will change the port no. your problem will be solve.

Comment: Thanks, I change http port 8080 to 8090. It solved my problem, tomcat does not start any more. But I don't understand why was it running?

Comment: becouse 8080 port no. is bydefault so when you start any server or try to run any web app in server it first go to 8080 and run that server which contains 8080 port .